# How to optimize "text search" for inverted index and relational database?

Tags: algorithm, architecture, full-text-search, search-engine, inverted-index

## Update 2022-08-12

I re-thought about it and realized I was overcomplicating it. I found the best way to enhance this system is by using good old information retrieval techniques ie using 'location' of a word in a sentence and 'ranking' queries to display best hits. The approach is illustrated in this following picture.

[image: enhanced retrieval using location and ranking]

---

## Update 2015-10-15

Back in 2012, I was building a personal online application and actually wanted to re-invent the wheel because am curious by nature, for learning purposes and to enhance my algorithm and architecture skills. I could have used apache lucene and others, however as I mentioned I decided to build my own mini search engine.

**Question:** So is there really no way to enhance this architecture except by using available services like elasticsearch, lucene and others?

---

## Original question

I am developing a web application, in which users search for specific titles (say for example : book x, book y, etc..) , which data is in a relational database (MySQL).

I am following the principle that each record that was fetched from the db, is cached in memory , so that the app has less calls to the database.

I have developed my own mini search engine , with the following architecture:
[image: Architecture diagram]

This is how it works:

- a) User searches a record name
- b) The system check what character the query starts with, checks if query there : get record. If not there, adds it and get all matching records from database using two ways:

- Either query already there in the Table "Queries" (which is a sort of history table) thus get record based on IDs (Fast performance)
- Or, otherwise using **Mysql LIKE %% statement** to get records/ids (Also then keep the used query by the user in history table Queries along with the ids it maps to). 
  -->Then It adds records and their ids to the   **cache** and Only the ids to the inverted index map.

  - c) results are returned to the UI

The system works fine, however I have  **Two** main issues, that i couldn't find a good solution for (been trying for the past month):

**First issue:** 
if you check point (b) , case where no query "history" is found and it has to use the **Like %%** statement : this process becomes **time** consuming when the query matches numerous records in the database (instead of one or two):

- It will take some time to get records from Mysql (this is why i used INDEXES on the specific columns)
- Then time to save query history
- Then time to add records/ids to cache and inverted index maps

**Second issue:** 
The application allows users to add themselves new records, that can **immediately** be used by other users logged in the to application.
However to achieve this, inverted index map and table "queries" have to be updated so that in case any old query matches to the new word. For example if a **new** record "woodX" is being added, still the old query "wood" does map to it. So in order to re-hook query "wood" to this new record, here is what i am doing now:

- new record "woodX" gets added to "records" table
- then i run a **Like %%** statement to see which  **already existing** query in table "queries" does map to this record(for example "wood"), then add this query with the new record id as a new row: [ wood, new id].
- Then in memory, update inverted index Map's "wood" key's value (ie the list), by adding the new record Id to this list

--> Thus now if a remote user searches "wood" it will get from  **memory** : wood and woodX

The **Issue**  here is also **time consumption**. Matching all query histories (in table queries) with the newly added word takes a lot of time (the more matching queries, the more time). Then the in memory update also takes a lot of time.

What i am **thinking** of doing to fix this time issue, is to return the desired results to the user  **first** , then let the application POST an  **ajax** call with the required data to achieve all these UPDATE tasks. But i am not sure if this is a bad practice or an unprofessional way of doing things? 
So for the past month ( a bit more) i tried to think of the best optimization/modification/update for this architecture, but I am not an expert in the document retrieval field (actually its my first mini search engine ever built).

I would appreciate any feedback or guidance on what i should do to be able to achieve this kind of architecture.
Thanks in advance.

**PS:**

- Its a j2ee application using servlets.
- I am using MySQL innodb (thus i cannot use full-text search option)

---

Comment: Is the search history (basically everything you cache) scoped by user, or is it the same for the whole application? I.e. will user 2 be able to find a cached object because user 1 already looked for the same key?

Comment: @theDmi yes it is a shared cache (like singleton)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend Sphinx Search Server, wchich is best optimized in full-text searching. Visit http://sphinxsearch.com/.

It's designed to work with MySQL, so it's an addition to Your current workspace.

Comment: I mentionned that I am using MySQL innodb (full text search doesn't work in it), does sphinx work with innodb?

Comment: it seems it does! http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=479

Answer (score 2):

I do not pretend to have THE solution but here is my ideas.
First, I though like you for time-consuming queries LIKE%% : I would execute a query limited to a few answers in MySQL, like a dozen, return that to user, and wait to see if user wants more matching records, or launch in background the full-query, depending on you indexation needs for future searches.

More generally, I think that storing everything in memory could lead, one day, to too-much memory consumption. And althrough the search-engine becomes faster and faster when it keeps everything in memory, you'll have to keep all these caches up-to-date when data is added or updated and it will certainly take more and more time.

That's why I think the solution I saw a day in an "open-source forum software" (I couldn't remember its name) is not too bad for text searching in posts : each time a data is inserted, a table named "Words" keeps tracks of every existing word, and another table (let's say "WordsLinks") the link between each word and posts it appears in.
This kind of solution has some drawbacks:

- Each Insert, Delete, Update in database is a lot slower
- Data selection for search engine must be anticipated : if you choose to keep two letter words you never kept, it is too late for already recorded data, unless you launch a complete data re-processing.
- You must take care of DELETE as well as UPDATE and INSERT

But I think there are some big advantages:

- Computing time is probably the same than the "memory solution" (eventually), but it is divided in each database Create/Update/Delete, rather than at query time.
- Looking for a whole word, or words "starting with" is instantaneous : when indexed, searching in "Words" table is dichotomic. And "WordLinks" table query is very fast either with an index.
- Looking for multiple words at the same time could be simple : gather a group of "WordLinks" for each found Word, and execute an intersection on them to keep only "Database Ids" common to all these groups. For example with the words "tree" and "leaf", the first one could give Table records {1, 4, 6}, and the second one could give {1, 3, 6, 9}. So with an intersection it is simple to keep only common parts : {1, 6}.
- A "Like %%" in a single-column table is probably faster than a lot of "Like %%" in different fields of different tables. And each database engine handles some cache : "Words" table could be little enough to be kept in memory
- I think there is a small risk of performance and memory problems if data becomes huge.
- As every search is fast, you can even look for synonyms. For example search "network" if user didn't find anything with "ethernet".
- You can apply rules, like splitting camel case words to generate for example the 3 words "wood", "X", "woodX" from "woodX". Each "word" is very lightweight to store and find, so you can do a lot of things.

I think the solution you need could be a blend of methods : for example you can keep lightweight UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, and launch "Words" and "WordsLinks" feeding from a TRIGGER.

Just for anecdote, I saw a software developped by my company in which it was decided to keep "everything" (!) in memory. It leads us to recommend to our customers to buy servers with 64GB RAM. A little bit expensive. It explains why I am very prudent when I see solutions that could lead, eventually, to memory filling.

Answer (score 2):

I have to say, I don't think your design fits the problem very well. The issues that you see now are consequences of that. And apart from that, your current solution doesn't scale.

Here is a possible solution:

1. Redesign your database to only contain authoritative data, but no derived data. So all cache entries must vanish from MySQL.
2. Keep data only for the duration of a request in memory within your application. This makes the design of your application much simpler (think race conditions) and enables you to scale to a sensible number of clients.
3. Introduce a caching layer. I'd strongly recommend to use an established product, rather than building this yourself. This frees you of all the custom built caching logic in your application and even does the job much better.

You can take a look at Redis or Memcached for the caching layer. I think an LRU strategy should fit here. Depending on how complex your queries become, a dedicated indexed search mechanism like Lucene might make sense as well.

Comment: for 1-the cache entries in MySQL are there for when i restart the server to refetch already existing query terms.
2- The whole point is having shared queries data in memories available to all users of the application in realtime.
3- correct, however this was done in 2012 and for a personal project where I actually wanted to re-invent the wheel to learn (should have mentioned that) but you are 100% correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this can be implemented in MySQL but it would be a lot less effort to just use an existing search-oriented database such as [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch). It uses Lucene library to implement the inverted index, has extensive documentation, supports horizontal scaling, fairly simple query language and so forth. I guess it has been quite a lot of work to get this far, and it will be even more work to handle caches, race conditions, bugs, performance issues etc. to make the solution "production grade".

Comment: I could have used apache lucene in 2012, however I wanted to build my own engine out of curiosity and learning purpose, for a personal online project. How can this be implemented in MySQL?

Comment: Re-inventin stuff is always very educational :) I am having difficulties on following details of this question but with proper tokenization I imagine you'd only need `WHERE pattern LIKE "quer%'` kind of queries (prefix match) which are more efficient than arbitrary `WHERE pattern LIKE "%quer%'` queries (assuming sane MySQL index, should check docs).

I don't think in-memory aspect is so important here, main point is that MySQL (or which ever db) has a suitable index to fulfill your queries. Having cached queries and results in db seems to complicate things too much.